# Steam workshop distribution/CDN?

Tags: steam

Does anyone know how the Steam workshop CDN works?

I use the Miami Steam server because I'm in Florida, and, with games I get a good 3.5MB/s download speed, however, with the Steam workshop items I get barely 700KB/s. Does anyone know the reasoning for this? Is it because they don't distribute content globally for user based items? Or, is it because they're smaller objects (~100MB vs ~8GB)? Or 'because Valve'?

(I did google first, all I see is a lot of people asking the same thing with no answers.)

Comment: I don't know that anyone outside Valve can answer this question.

Comment: @Shinrai Then we can get this site popular enough that a Valve employee joins our ranks or someone can [ask Valve](https://support.steampowered.com/) and give an answer.  Personally I like the first option.  Other possibility is to..."Reverse Engineer" Steam.

Comment: @Betophoiba, In fact, this gave me an idea. I'll later look into the way SteamRE deals with Workshop items. Thanks mate!

Comment: Apparently it uses the same server, based on the steamRE source, however, steamRE only gets information about games/workshop and doesn't download them. Maybe it's a different server for that, or, maybe I just read the code wrong (hopefully not).

Comment: Well I guess you could record the network traffic to/from your computer and see where you go when you download something from Steam Workshop

Answer (score 0):

Games are broken into many small parts which can be downloaded in parallel.  Workshop items are a single large file which does not benefit from multiple HTTP connections.